# The importance of 'SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)' in DapperORM

Tags: c#, .net, orm, frameworks, dapper

I am new to C# and definitely new to Dapper.NET. This is the first time I'm tackling ORMs and frameworks so I would like to know more about some syntax.

I've seen several `INSERT` queries and noticed that all have this

```
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);
```

after the `INSERT INTO...;` line.

I would like to know the importance, or use of this. Thank you

Edit: here is some code I've written, and is working as far as I have tested.

This is the `Users.cs`:

```
public class Users
{
    private int _uid;
    private string _fullname;
    private string _username;
    private string _passcode;

    public int uid
    {
        get { return _uid; }
        set { _uid = value; }
    }

    public string fullname
    {
        get { return _fullname; }
        set { _fullname = value; }
    }

    public string username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; }
    }

    public string passcode
    {
        get { return _passcode; }
        set { _passcode = value; }
    }
}
```

and this is the `insertUser.cs`:

```
public Users InsertData(Users newUser)
{
    string strQry = @"INSERT INTO [Users] VALUES (@uid, @fullname, @username, @passcode);
                      SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [uid] = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);";

    using(var conn = InitOpenConn())
    {
        try
        {
            var ins = conn.Query<Users>(strQry, newUser).Single();

            return ins;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is `Program.cs`:

```
InsertUser ium = new InsertUser();

try
{
    Users newUser = new Users
            {
                uid = 10,
                fullname = "James Bond",
                username = "james007",
                passcode = "095e3cbaf34467fbe1b0f4cd846a57460718d2b4ca504caca28ae5287e8d076db3ddadac11db87ab6ac9dac4b8d84d9a65e67e98ab6ef979c61f277f51df36f3"
            };

    Users insUsr = ium.InsertData(newUser);

    refreshTable();
    MessageBox.Show("Added !");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you insert a new row into a SQL Server table with an `Identity` column, the ORM needs to get the generated ID from the database in order to update your model directly in the application.

Example:

```
/****************** pseudo code ******************/

    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
    obj.SomeProperty = someValue;
    // INSERT TO database with Dapper and return inserted ID
    int insertedID = SomeMethodToInsertUsingDapper(obj);        
    obj.ID = insertedID;

    // The generated ID is get from the database using
    // SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);
    // so this next line prints the ID generated in the database.
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ID);
```

***Dapper Limitations:***

**Dapper has some limitation on the Identity Column**, So people using `Dapper` use this SQL syntax `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)` to get the generated `ID` from the `database`. And then use that `ID` in the `application`.

> Identity Column in a numeric column in the database that gets
>   incremented automatically on each insert.

Comment: This is true for **SQL Server** - other RDBMS might handle this all differently...

Comment: @marc_s SCOPE_IDENTITY() syntax is only valid for SQL Server.

Comment: so in simpler terms for newbies like me, that line is for ?

Comment: @TheQuestioner which line exactly ?

Comment: @TheQuestioner Sorry, maybe i dropped some important information that i thought was trivial. Check my answer now.

Comment: its ok. i saw the updated answer too. exactly how i want it to be explained too. thanks for the help :)

Comment: PS: this has *nothing* to do with whether or not that `identity` column is the primary key (or not) - this is **only** relevant because it is an **identity** column....

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
```

This line of code returns the last inserted **identity** ID of the table.

We have many use of this. Like we checked value inserted or not and also if you want some perform some operation on current inserted current.

If you are using EF(ORM) then and you table is EMp_master then you can get current inserted ID using below syntax

```
EMp_master obj=new Emp_master
obj.first="suraj";
obj.Emp_master.add(obj);
obj.savechagnes();

int currentinsertedid = obj.empid   // this syntax same as  SELECT 

CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) both give same record.
```

Comment: i see. thanks !. it's all clear to me now. although, is it mandatory to add `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);` to every `INSERT...` query i execute ?.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with whether that column is the primary key (or not) - it **only** matters that this column is an **identity** column (and yes - *most often*, those identity columns *are* the primary key - but that's not the reason why you need to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the last inserted ID...)